# How can I save Playwright visual regression reference screenshots in one folder

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I want to store reference screenshots in one folder for a better control over it and to update when there are any changes. Here is my test case

```
test('Add Visual regression tests', async ({ page }, testInfo) => {
  await page.goto('/add-visual-regression');

  const screenshotFileName = 'add-visual-regression.png';
  
  await expect(page).toHaveScreenshot({ path: `./screenshots/${testInfo.title}.png`, 
  fullPage: true });

});
```

I expect the screenshot to be saved(if there isn't any) in screenshots folder and if there is one, then compare with it.

However, I can find [page.screenshot](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-screenshot)() to have path as an optional argument but I do not find such option for [page.toHaveScreenshot](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-pageassertions#page-assertions-to-have-screenshot-1)()

I wonder if there is a way to achieve that functionality.

Comment: I think you're correct. Doesn't look like you can't change the directory used / created by `toHaveScreenshot()`.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, its not possible to have a unified folder/directory to save the baseline screenshots. Every .spec.js file will create its own folder/directory with the file name and use it as baseline image/screenshot reference.